# Not able to view page while clicking on View on site in Content manager

Tags: dxa, dxa-dotnet, tridion-sites

[image]

I'm trying to view page on site with DXA staging but getting following error. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a misconfiguration, as it is pointing to localhost (127.0.0.1). Is that expected?

Comment: IIRC, The "View on Site" feature uses the *first* Website Base URL, as configured in Topology Management (run `Get-TtmWebsite` in Powershell to see how your Websites are configured in Topology Manager).